# Is there a way to change the call screen in lumia 535?

Tags: 8.1, settings, lock-screen, calls, nokia-lumia-535

Can I change the call screen in Lumia? Lumia 535 has a touch issue and therefore I miss many call trying to swipe up before saying "answer or ignore". Is there a way that I can avoid this swipe up screen and straight away go to "answer or ignore screen"? Please advice.

Comment: Do you have all the latest updates installed?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot change the way calls are being displayed. The swipe issue you are describing is a known bug for some Lumias. A quick fix should be to turn the screen off and back on before swiping up.

Comment: That works when my fingers are dry. But when there is moisture, that doesn't work as well!!!! I have the latest updates for lumia denim.Will installing windows 10 help?

Answer (score 0):

as I can't comment...
this touch issue can be fully solved only by hardware fix, they erleased few "final" fixes, every one helped a bit and upgrading to update 2 not released officialy made touch **almost** fine, but never solved problems completely.
For me touch sometimes just declines to work if device gets too hot due to stress and/or charging, moisture also breaks a lot
and unfortunately cold too